# About FD_SET and fd_set in linux

Tags: c, linux, select, g++

My os is 64bits Centos6.4. I have a question about how to fd_set manage FD_SET add the fd.Follow code is case:

```
fd_set my_set;
FD_SET(31, &my_set);
```

Then, I show my_set.fds_bits[...].The my_set.fds_bits[0] is equal to 0x0000000080000000, my_set.fds_bits[1~...] is zero.I can understand the result.But I also write an case,Follow code:

```
fd_set my_set;
FD_SET(63, &my_set);
```

I show my_set.fds_bits[...].The my_set.fds_bits[0] is equal to 0x0.In my opinion, the result should be my_set.fds_bits[0] is equal to 0x8000000000000000.I really don't understand why sencond result is 0x0. Doesn't fd that is equal to 63 have a state in my_set.

Here is full testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

void printFDSET(fd_set target_sets)
{
    int uIndex = 0;
    int model_num = __NFDBITS;
    for(uIndex = 0; uIndex < 10/*FD_SETSIZE/model_num*/; uIndex++)
    {
        printf("0x%016x\t", target_sets.fds_bits[uIndex]);
        if(uIndex % 4 == 3)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fd_set my_set;
    FD_ZERO(&my_set);

    printf("sizeof(long int) = %d\n", sizeof(long int));
    printf("FD_SETSIZE = %d\n", FD_SETSIZE);
    printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof __FDS_BITS(&my_set)[0]);
    printf("\n\n");

    int unfd = 31;
    FD_SET(unfd, &my_set);
    printf("%d is added to my_set:\n", unfd);
    printFDSET(my_set);
    printf("\n\n");

    FD_CLR(unfd, &my_set);
    unfd = 63;
    printf("%d is added to my_set:\n", unfd);
    FD_SET(unfd, &my_set);
    printFDSET(my_set);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof __FDS_BITS(&my_set)[0])`?

Comment: @Armali,The result is eight.

Comment: Interesting… How exactly did you print the second result (so that I can try it)?

Comment: @Armali,update question.I added a full testing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't fd that is equal to 63 have a state in my_set.

It has. You just didn't correctly print the value, because you forgot the length modifier `l` in the `printf` format string.

```
        printf("0x%016lx\t", __FDS_BITS(&target_sets)[uIndex]);
```

Comment: ,Oh, I got it. I missed format string of printf function.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably compiled your code as 32 bit. set.fds_bits is an array of long int. Check the value of my_set.fds_bits[1]

Comment: ,I compiled my program by using -m64.The result is no change.